# react webpack breaks when i import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, axios

so I'm having a lot of trouble configuring webpack on a react app that I have to setup from scratch. The issue is that when I import axios in my App.js webpack fails without any errors, it says that it was compiled successfully but only serves the bare index.html and if I just comment out the axios import line it goes back to normal here's my code bellow:

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
//import axios from 'axios'
import Login from './Components/Login'
import Test from './Components/Test'
import './Styles/App.css'

const App = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(true)

    const isUserValid = () => {

    }

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <Router>
                {!user ? (
                    <Login />
                ) : (
                    <>
                        <div className="app__body">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/"><Test /></Route>
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )}
            </Router>
        </div>

    );
};

export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "base react app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --hot --open --mode development --client-logging verbose",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.17.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.58.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    client: {
      logging: 'info',
    },
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react'),
    },
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".scss"],
    fallback: {
      assert: false,
      http: false,
      https: false,
      zlib: false,
      tty: false,
      util: false,
      fs: false,
      net: false,
      stream: false
    }
  },
  target: "web",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: 'babel-loader', },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/styles.css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

I really would aprreciate if anyone could help solve this problem it's been driving me crazy.

Comment: _"only serves the bare index.html"_... any errors reported in the browser console? Have you made sure Axios is actually installed? Tried the old failsafe `rm -r node_modules package-lock.json && npm i` (or Yarn equivalent `rm -r node_modules yarn.lock && yarn`)?

Comment: I check the browser console and it indeed reports an error "Cannot access '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization" I read that this might be due to cyclic dependencies, but I don't know how to solve it, and yes I made sure that everytihng was installed correctly